# Views in Gallery View loses "focus" when invalidated or on navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have created a Gallery View with 2 Views with 3 simple TextViews to present some
of the data from my data model.
Upon calling the Invalidate method on the 2 Views it is like the
Views lose focus, the same case when I navigate in the Gallery View.

The text becomes almost unreadable after the "focus" is lost. (See the two pictures below)

I am using Monodroid, but regular Android examples are appreciated as well.

The code for my Gallery View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Gallery
    android:id="@+id/locationGallery"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

  </Gallery>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code for the two Views I put into the Gallery View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3sp"
    android:id="@+id/locationGalleryItem"
    >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text2"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/text1"
      android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/text3"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@id/text2"
      android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem by making an EventHandler for the ItemSelected property on the Gallery View. This EventHandler tracks the current position of the Gallery View. Then invokes the method SetSelection on the Gallery View to the current position. This gives the desired result.

Code:

```
locationGallery.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<ItemEventArgs>(locationGallery_ItemSelected);

void locationGallery_ItemSelected(object sender, ItemEventArgs e)
{
    var send = sender as Gallery;
    send.SetSelection(e.Position);
}
```

Comment: Using this is a bit buggy and when scrolling it is a bit choppy and sometimes snaps to one of the child views. Going to look for another solution.

I was researching Gallery View and it seems like it does not have default focus functionality, so that might be why unselectedAlpha is ignored completely.

Comment: So I actually ended up making a port of a horizontal pager which can be found here: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MonoDroid.HorizontalPager

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the easiest way to solve it would be to add the following to your Gallery (unless you need it of course):

```
android:unselectedAlpha="1.0"
```

Comment: That did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: The Gallery view will by default show children slightly transparent when they're unselected. The code above will remove that transparency.

Comment: For some reason the transparency keeps staying on all children. Though I think I have found a solution. I will try messing a bit around with it before posting to test that it really works.